# How to make a filling algorithm/animation similar to the one in procreate?

Tags: python, opencv, animation, flood-fill

I am working on an aesthetically pleasing flood fill algorithm and I find the flood fill animation in procreate to be quite pleasing. after putting it in slow-mo I realized that the animation itself has this circular filling pattern and it seems to create color gradients that vary in sizes surrounding the actual color. I made a video showing this: [normal speed and slow-mo video](https://clipchamp.com/watch/JH8tbbIT7Yn)

also here is my non recursive flood fill algorithm:

```
import mahotas
import numpy as np
import cv2 as cv
from shapely.geometry import Polygon


def flood_fill(poly, new_color):
    
    # separate the x's and y's
    xs = [i[0] for i in poly.exterior.coords]
    ys = [i[1] for i in poly.exterior.coords]
    minx, maxx = min(xs), max(xs)
    miny, maxy = min(ys), max(ys)
    X = int(maxx - minx)
    Y = int(maxy - miny)
    # create a new polygon cord that have no excess white space 
    newPoly = [(int(x - minx), int(y - miny))
               for (x, y) in poly.exterior.coords]
    # creates a mask for all the points in the polygon
    grid = np.zeros((X, Y), dtype=np.int8)
    mahotas.polygon.fill_polygon(newPoly, grid)
    # after masking return to points and translate back to original positions
    points = [[x + minx, y + miny] for (x, y) in zip(*np.nonzero(grid))]


    # now turn all the corresponding pixels in the blank_iamge to a desiered color
    for x, y in points:
        blank_image[int(y), int(x)] = np.array(new_color)

# create a blank image
blank_image = np.zeros((300, 400, 3), np.uint8)
blank_image[:, :] = (255, 255, 255)


flood_fill(poly=Polygon([[0,0],[0,100],[100,100],[100,0]]),new_color= (255,0,0))

cv.imshow("blank",blank_image)
cv.waitKey(0)
```

note I would like to keep my polygon filling functionality I just need to create an animation for the filling pattern and the gradient effect shown in the video.
Sadly, I have no idea how to implement that.

Answer (score 0):

Fill the shape in an auxiliary image (not displayed), to generate a mask. Then perform filling using any visual effect (such as a growing disk), and only update inside the mask.

Comment: sorry but i cant really get the idea of using auxiliary images for masking or growing disks (I am kind of new to this field and I'm not exactly well acquainted with these ideas) is there a code that does this or you've written a code that utilizes the techniques mentioned in your answer??

Comment: @Learner: no, I haven't.

Comment: I know it sounds like I am asking a lot ,but can you create one? I honestly cant figure out how to do it and there is not enough resources for me to use about those topics on the internet.

Comment: @Learner: right, you are asking too much.